# Configuration parameter in xdebug for allowing multiple hosts on remote machine

Tags: php, xdebug, zend-debugger

I am working on one web application. The project located on my linux box i.e. server.
We are remotely accessing this machine from Windows.

I am using xdebug for debugging along with Eclipse PDT.

xdebug is installed on my server. The below configuration is set in the `php.ini` file (which is  located on the server):

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug.log
```

After doing the above configuration setting in php.ini for xdebug, it's allowing only one host ( i.e. 10.88.36.1)

I want to allow for multiple hosts. I know in zend debugger there is a configuration parameter option which does this i.e.

```
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=10.88.36.28, 10.88.36.1
```

Is there an equivalent option for xdebug so that i can able to allow multiple hosts to have access to server remotely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This discussion](http://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/1750.html) suggests using a 'DBGp proxy'. The linked PDF gives a general idea of what to look for. Further research shows only one implementation: Active State DBGp Proxy which is distributed as part of the Komodo package. Configuration is [documented here](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/debugger.html#dbgp_proxy). A slightly older version is [available separately](http://community.activestate.com/komodo-5-remote-debugging-package-downloads).

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure if this is a perfect solution for your problem but I found that it will accept multiple hosts in this fashion:

```
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.1
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.2
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.3
xdebug.remote_host=10.88.36.4
```

Although multiple connections will not be able to debug at once, if a machine is listed here it should be able to connect. Also correct me if I'm wrong but block definitions do NOT work (ex. 10.88.36.0/24) as far as I can tell.

Source: me mucking around